# Pagination in jquerymobile is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-pagination

I am new to jquery and their plugins...and also creating issue first time...for any mistakes please help me to improve...

I am using jquerymobile for my website. in my website there is a search field which results lots of records so i wants to use pagination to show my results...

I used [JQuery Mobile Pagination Plugin.][1]

But its not working as expected.

In android browser, it stops dragging after two Pages..and in opera browser when i ran the  code browser hangs...

I am not able to catch whether problem is with my code or there is any plugin support problem with these browser...

please help me...to understand this. if you already used this plugin.
Any help would be much appreciated.
    **This problem occurs when our html form name are like**
    http://abc/def.html?search_form_id=30&keyword=denim&submit_btn=Search#/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=denim&search_form_id=90&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=1
    http://abc/def.html?search_form_id=30&keyword=denim&submit_btn=Search#/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=denim&search_form_id=90&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=2
    http://abc/def.html?search_form_id=30&keyword=denim&submit_btn=Search#/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=denim&search_form_id=90&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=3
    http://abc/def.html?search_form_id=30&keyword=denim&submit_btn=Search#/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=denim&search_form_id=90&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=4
    these names are different only from 1 argument that is **page_no** and these urls are generated dynamically. **Here is my code. i am using perl language.**
   in this case i am not able to use jquery mobile pagination plugin.
    my $current_page = $form_data{page_no} || 1;
    my ($prev_p,$next_p) ;
    if($current_page > 1) {
          $prev_p = $current_page - 1;
    }
    else {
    $prev_p = $current_page;
    }
    $next_p = $current_page + 1;
    <\ul data-role="pagination"><\li class="ui-pagination-prev"><\a href="/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=<% $keyword %>&search_form_id=30&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=<% $prev_p %>">Prev\</li>
    <\li class="ui-pagination-next"><\a href="/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=<% $keyword %>&search_form_id=30&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=<% $next_p %>">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
    plz help now...

Comment: Holy ellipses. What's your question? You need to give much more details instead od "It's not working as expected".

Comment: Basically, i want to know why mobile browser is hanging when i run the code in mobile...while in desktop its working is fine...

Comment: "plz help now..." really? kind'a rude no?

Comment: its not rude...sorry..if you felt its rude..i just wants to post details nothing else..my intention is not rude..

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to clode  tag in the Prev button

```
    <ul data-role="pagination">
        <li class="ui-pagination-prev">
            <a href="/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=<% $keyword %>&search_form_id=30&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=<% $prev_p %>">Prev</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-pagination-next">
            <a href="/mobile_app/search_action.html?keyword=<% $keyword %>&search_form_id=30&submit_btn=Search&set=1&page_no=<% $next_p %>">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) in jquery mobile documentation. In details I focus on the last paragraph "Passing parameters between pages".

Maybe your link is passing parameters to the next page but jquery mobile framework doesn't like it this way